# Laravel with Sofa Eloquence returns duplicate search results

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5 with Sofa Eloquence https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence. The search query works great however it returns duplicate at time multiple of the same search results.

My controller:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function results( Request $request )
    {
        // get search criteria
        $q = Input::get('q');

        // check if request is null
        if ( !$q )
        {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
        else
        {
            $articles = Article::search('%'.$q.'%')
                     ->where('eHArt_Status', 1)
                     ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
                     ->paginate(10);

            return view('components.search')
                        ->with('criteria', $q)
                        ->with('articles', $articles);
        }
    }
}
```

So as an example. if i search for an article with the criteria: "Security", it will find the correct results but duplicate them multiple times. sometimes up to 5 of the same result.

and guidance on this would be great thanx.

Comment: Maybe you have few articles with this word in it's text?

Comment: Yes there would be many articles with that keyword, however it returns the same "article" many times in the results search feed.

Comment: You can try ->groupBy('article_id').